# display doesn't show an element in MaterialUi in breakpoints

Tags: material-ui, display, box

I have a `box component`. I need to hide it if `props` are false and show if one of them is true. But when `props` are true, it is hidden. But when I switch to another component and return to those with boxes, it becomes visible.

```
<Box                              
            component={Grid}
            display={{
              xs: error || activity ? "block" : "none",
              sm: error || activity ? "block" : "none",
              md: "block",
            }}
           
          >
            <Component/>
          </Box>
```

Comment: I could solve the problem by adding and changing key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to just use a condition in your return to display it or not.

```
function theBox(props){
  return (
  { props.display &&
         <Box                              
            component={Grid}
            display={{
              xs: error || activity ? "block" : "none",
              sm: error || activity ? "block" : "none",
              md: "block",
            }}
          >
            <Component/>
          </Box> 
  }
 );
}
```